# Please anyone give me idea how to populate two result sets into gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two stored procedures which gives Daily swipe data and another gives Temporary Swipe details.
I got an requirement to populate gridview, Based on the date the temporary card details must get displayed in between Daily swipe data.
Please anyone give me idea how to populate two result sets into  gridview

Iam using Sql server 2008 R2 and Visualstudio 2010

Comment: The below is the Post, Hope it may help to get some information.
Two dataTables- 1 Gridview! clearly mentioned way in the under post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume we consume this ResultSet which has two DataTables "Agent" and "RealEstateProperty". The task is to display, what properties belongs to which agent, in a GridView.

[image]

There are different ways to accomplish this task-

**Method 1: Bind DataTables to  a single GridView**

To bind these multiple DataTables to a single GridView control, we can quickly create a new temporary DataTable, with the required fields and populate the Rows and then bind the new DataTable Rows to the GridView.

[image]

The above code is self explanatory, where I have created a temporary DataTable, populated its rows by iterating through the original DataTables and then binded the Grid to the new DataTable.Rows. The interesting piece of code to note here is the row.GetChildRows(), which respects the relationship and automatically returns the related child rows. The aspx part looks like the following, where we have a GridView with three columns.
[image]

and the RowDataBound code is

[image]

**Method 2: Bind DataTables to a nested GridView**

If we want to avoid creating temporary dummy DataTable as described in method 1, we can use the technique of nested list control. Now we can do this by using

two GridView, or
two DataList, or
two Repeaters or
a combination of Repeater and GridView, or
a combination of Repeater and DataList, or
a combination of GridView and DataList.

We are going to look at a combination of 2 GridViews here, where one GridView is nested inside another, you can do any of the above combinations. For this case the the aspx code is-

[image]
Notice the parent and nested GridViews has different onrowdatabound methods. In this technique the parent grid is binded to the the Agent DataTable Rows and the nested GridView is binded to the child RealEstateProperty DataTable Rows. Here is the code.

[image]

**Method 3: Convert the DataSet to Objects and then bind to GridView**

We can generate csharp class from the dataset schema using Xsd.exe and then bind the GridViews to the objects. I have discussed similar technique in one of my previous blog post, where you will find how we can use the Xsd.exe that ships with the .NET Framework.

Example
    C:\temp>xsd propertyDataSet.xsd /l:cs /c
    Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
    [Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.42]
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Writing file 'C:\temp\propertydatasetclass.cs'.

I also demonstrated a handy DataTableToT() method to assist in converting DataTable to strongly typed object. And when we have the DataTable converted to a stronglytyped object/list/collection it is very easy to bind to the bind to the GridView.

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Call your Second stored procedure within first stored procedure.
2.Pass your outcome to dataset.
3.From dataset u can fetch it using ds.table[0],ds.table[1],etc..
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

you can find from here, Merging DataSet Contents
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszytsd8.aspx